# Signalr - Cannot connect to hub from child directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I can register SignalR middleware using the following code in an ASP .NET application:

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {

        app.MapSignalR();

    }

}
```

I can prove this works as I can access the "/signalr/hubs" URL, which is for the automatically generated JavaScript file.

I can connect to the hub from a page located on the root ./Default.aspx using

```
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="./Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>

<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="./signalr/hubs"></script>
```

When I enter the command `$.connection.chatHub;` I get

```
init {state: {…}, connection: h…n.fn.init, hubName: "chathub", _: {…}, 
client: {…}, …}
client
:
{}
connection
:
hubConnection.fn.init {url: "/signalr", qs: null, lastError: null, _: {…}, 
logging: false, …}
hubName
:
"chathub"
server
:
{connect: ƒ, sendPrivateMessage: ƒ}
state
:
{}
_
:
{callbackMap: {…}}
__proto__
:
Object
```

However I cannot connect from a page located in a sub directory using the following code:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>

<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src= "../signalr/hubs"></script>
```

When I try to connect to the hub using the command `$.connection.chatHub;` I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chatHub' of undefined
at <anonymous>:1:14
```

I've already searched for similar issues on Google and stackoverflow without success.

Can someone help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to map SignalR hubs to the app builder pipeline at "/signalr".

```
var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
```

And you can try to bundle and render it to your view.

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/signalR").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.min.js"
));
```

**In your view:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalR")
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```